Rails Sets a Cookie on a Subdomain for GET Requests but Not for POST Requests
I have a subdomain b.test.com that makes request to another subdomain a.test. When the request is GET type the cookie and session are set correctly in b.test but if I change to POST they are no longer set.
Please if anyone knows how to fix it.
This is the actions test1 is GET and test2 is POST
def test1
    Rails.logger.info "**session #{session['test23']}**" if session['test23'].present?
    Rails.logger.info "**cookie #{cookies['test24']}**" if cookies['test24'].present?
    session['test23'] = 'works session!'
    # Generate cookie
    cookies['test24'] =
      {
        value: 'works cookie!',
        domain: ".shipedge.com",
        path: '/',
        same_site: :strict,
        expires: 8.hours.from_now,
        secure: true,
        httponly: true
      }
    
    render(json: { address: 'Av. Busch 3454', city: 'La Paz' }, status: :ok)

def test2
    Rails.logger.info "**session #{session['test23']}**" if session['test23'].present?
    Rails.logger.info "**cookie #{cookies['test24']}**" if cookies['test24'].present?
    session['test23'] = 'works session!'
    # Generate cookie
    cookies['test24'] =
      {
        value: 'works cookie!',
        domain: ".shipedge.com",
        path: '/',
        same_site: :strict,
        expires: 8.hours.from_now,
        secure: true,
        httponly: true
      }
    
    render(json: { address: 'Av. Busch 3454', city: 'La Paz' }, status: :ok)

Routes:
get 'test_angular/test1'
post 'test_angular/test2'

CORS:
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins "a.test.com","b.test.com"

    # The resource(s) to allow CORS for
    resource '*',
             headers: :any,
             methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
             credentials: true,
  end
end

session_store.rb
Bla::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_bla_session',
                                      :domain => ".test.com",
                                      :tld_length => 2,
                                      :expire_after => 8.hours

Frontend Javascript:
test1 = 'https://a.test/test_angular/test1';
const getData2 = () => {
  return fetch(test1, { credentials: 'include', method: 'GET' })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => data);
};

test2 = 'https://a.test/test_angular/test2';
const getData3 = () => {
  return fetch(test2, { credentials: 'include', method: 'POST' })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => data);
};

Gem that I'm using:
gem 'rails_same_site_cookie'
Rails version 5.2
ruby('2.7.5')
